# Create a wrapper component which accepts props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of components which accept props like this

```
export default function Item1({fontSize, color, ...props}) {
  return (
      <SvgIcon
        fontSize={fontSize}
        color={color}
        viewBox="0 0 18 18"
        alignmentBaseline="middle"
        {...props}
      >
          <somethingElse />
      </SvgIcon>
  )
}
```

I want to create a wrapper class such that it accepts name of the item and returns these items. I created something but I feel it's not a good practise to write code like below:-

```
export default function WrapperComponent({name, fontSize, color, ...props }) {
  if(name === 'Item1'){
    return <Item1 fontSize={fontSize} color={color} />
  }
  if(name === 'Item2'){
    return <Item2 fontSize={fontSize} color={color} />
  }
  if(name === 'Item3'){
    return <Item3 fontSize={fontSize} color={color} />
  }
  return(
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I thought of creating a mapping here but I'm not sure how I can achieve that?

Comment: You can use conditional rendering and on basis of name of icon only render that icon

Comment: In component Item1 is only <SomethingElse /> is variable? And is  structure of all the other elements same? i.e they all have SvgIcon?

Comment: Yes, the structure of other elements is same. All include <SvgIcon> But I wanted to create a mapping for this somewhere

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need the name of the component to be dynamic. You can create an `items.js` file as follows:

```js
import Item1 from 'items/Item1';
import Item2 from 'items/Item2';
import Item3 from 'items/Item3';
// and so on...

const items = {
  item1: Item1,
  item2: Item2,
  item3: Item3,
  // and so on...
}

export const getItem = (name) => {
  return items[name];
}
```

In your wrapper, you can use the `getItem` function as follows:

```
import { getItem } from 'items';

export default function WrapperComponent({name, fontSize, color, ...props }) {
  const Item = getItem(name);

  if (Item) {
    return <Item fontSize={fontSize} color={color} />
  }

  return(
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I use this method for loading components into a modal component dynamically, and this should work for your use case.

I would also suggest in your case to make the `<SomethingElse />` component dynamic instead of `<ItemX />`.

Comment: The second `return` will never be reached

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the code to load the component conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

If this mapping is to be bound to the `WrapperComponent`, you can create a finite state with a plain JS object:

```js
const items = {
 Item1: ({fontSize, color}) => <Item1 fontSize={fontSize} color={color} />
 Item2: ({fontSize, color}) => <Item2 fontSize={fontSize} color={color} />
}

export default function WrapperComponent({name, fontSize, color, ...props }) {
  const item = items[name];

  if(item) {
    return item({ fontSize, color });
  }

  return(
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is an example in CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-finite-state-with-plain-js-object-rh9ktx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I find the `switch` statement useful for these situations. It returns something different depending on what your variable is. It also includes a default:

```
export default function WrapperComponent({name, fontSize, color, ...props }) {
  switch (name) {
    case 'Item1':
      return <Item1 fontSize={fontSize} color={color} />;
    case 'Item2':
      return <Item2 fontSize={fontSize} color={color} />;
    case 'Item3':
      return <Item3 fontSize={fontSize} color={color} />;
    default:
      return <div>{children}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want a map it for in the main entry file,you can have a clean code ,simple code and have a good sturcture,

if so ,i advise you new a config file ,write a function to return the item component, import it in the main entry file ,like the fellowing:

```js
// config.ts
export const ItemSvgRender =(props)=>{return ...};
// main.tsx
import {ItemSvgRender} from "./config.ts";

// use it
```